# Namespace object by its name

Tags: clojure, namespaces

Is there a way to get namespace object by its name? For example:

```
(def ns-symbol (ns-name *ns*))          ;; get namespace name as symbol
(def ns-object (ns-by-name ns-as-str))  ;; convert it back to namespace object
```

So in this example I need function `ns-by-name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(ns-name *ns*)` returns a symbol not a string, so your ns-as-str is misnamed...

```
(type (ns-name *ns*))
clojure.lang.Symbol
```

Given that, converting it back is as simple as...

```
(find-ns (ns-name *ns*))
#<Namespace user>
```

If you really want the name of the namespace to be a string...

```
(def ns-as-str (str (ns-name *ns*)))
(def ns-object (find-ns (symbol ns-as-str))
```

Comment: Actually I was interested on how to get namespace object from any representation, no matter string or symbol, so didn't pay much attention to return type of `ns-name`. Thanks for noticing, and for answer of course.

Answer (score 2):

The `find-ns` function would probably do the trick:

```
user=> (def ns-as-str (ns-name *ns*)) 
#'user/ns-as-str
user=> (def ns-object (find-ns ns-as-str)) 
#'user/ns-object
user=> ns-object
#<Namespace user>
```

Comment: `find-ns` seems to be more idiomatic, so I accepted @sw1nn's answer, but `create-ns` will definitely work too. Thanks.